# Display the same indexed value from 3 lists in python stock script

Tags: python-3.x

**Objective**

My goal is to have 3 lists for stocks and display same index position of each list based upon the matching value of a user input.

**My 3 lists**

```
Price = [37.10, 46.18, 51.76, 145.64]

Symbol = ['T', 'KO', 'ABQ', 'LOW']

Name = ['ATT', 'COCA COLA COMPANY', 'ABBOT LABORATORIES', 'LOWES COMPANY INC']
```

My script in full will ask the user for an `investment amount and if below $1000 it'll invest in the cheapest stock`.

`If over $1000, it'll invest in the most expensive stock`.

So `if under $1000, it should invest all the money into ATT at $37.10 per share`.

If `over $1000, it should invest all the money into LOW at $145.64 a share`.

The output should display the purchase amount of shares for the given stock it invested in.

**Output to user**

How much are you wanting to invest today? 1001.57

Below are the stocks available for purchase:

```
Price | Symbol | Name 

$ 37.1 | T | ATT

$ 46.18 | KO | COCA COLA COMPANY

$ 51.76 | ABT | ABBOTT LABORATORIES

$ 145.64 | LOW | LOWES COMPANIES INC
```

**This will purchase 26.99 shares of 'T:ATT' at $37.1 per share.**

**This will purchase 6.87 shares of 'LOW:LOWES COMPANIES INC' at $145.64 per share.**

## My code is as follows:

```
investing = (float(input("How much are you wanting to invest today? ")))

print ("\nBelow are the stocks available for purchase:")

print ("\nLast Trade | Symbol | Name ")

for pr, sy, na, in sorted(zip(stock_price, stock_symbol, stock_name)):
    print ('$',pr, '|',sy, '|',na)

cheapest_stock = (min(stock_price))

expensive_stock = (max(stock_price))

purchase_low = (investing/cheapest_stock) // 0.01 / 100

purchase_hi = (investing/expensive_stock) // 0.01 / 100


print (f"\nThis will purchase {purchase_amt} shares of 'T:ATT' at ${cheapest_stock} per share.")

print (f"\nThis will purchase {purchase_amt} shares of 'LOW:ATT' at ${expensive_stock} per share.")
```

Problem
I can not figure how to get the low value determined by `min(stock_price)` or the high value determined by `max(stock_price)` to display the matching values for the stock symbol and stock name from the other lists.

So I currently have it manually typed out in my print statements above.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly!

Comment: if the answer help you, dont forget to mark the answer as "accepted answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the Index of the min/max element in Price list and find the element in that index from other lists.

For ex: if you want the symbol for the lowest Price then below code gives the required result.

```
index=Price.index(min(Price)) #Gives the index of Minimum element in Price list
print(Symbol[index]) #prints the value of an element at an above index from list Symbol.

#or we can write as
Symbol[Price.index(min(Price))]
```

Use index() to get the index of an element.

```
lis.index("foo") #this code gives index of element "foo" in list lis.
```

Comment: One last request. When I invest 745.87 to purchase the cheap amount I'd like ti to show 2 decimal places. so 20.10 shares at $37.10 dollars per share. I've tried adding %.20f to my print statement and it doesn't work.


print (f"\n{guest}, we will invest your amount of ${investing} in purchasing {purchase_amt} shares of the Stock Symbol: '{symbol_lo}' and Stock Name: '{name_lo}' at ${cheapest_stock} dollars per share.")

Guy, we will invest your amount of $745.87 in purchasing 20.1 shares of the Stock Symbol: 'T' and Stock Name: 'ATT' at $37.1 dollars per share.

Comment: @cyberjax21 `print("%s, we will invest your amount of %.2f in purchasing %.2f shares of the Stock Symbol: %s and Stock Name: %s at $%.2f dollars per share." %(guest,investing,purchase_amt,symbol_lo,name_lo,cheapest_stock)) #This code gives the desired result.`